# visual studio Arabic texts : newline in constants

Tags: c++, unicode, arabic

I never faced this problem before but in my current project I tried to write some Arabic text in wide chars and I got this strange error

I wrote this for example :

```
LPWSTR data_post = L"ب";
```

and got C2001 error

I think visual studio adds something to the text like a new line

I made sure I'm using 'Use Unicode Character Set' in the charset settings

Comment: What version of VS are you using? What encoding are you using for the source file?

Comment: visual studio 2015 , and I don't know what is the encoding , the project was a small one that I downloaded from github then after I tested it I replaced its code with a new one instead of creating a new project

Comment: Embedding Unicode strings in source files can prove to be complicated.  You need to set the encoding for the source file (using an encoding the compiler can handle) and then workout how to embed the Unicode string in the source file with the right encoding.  I suggest you either use escape sequences; an external Unicode text file; or resource strings.  See here for encoding and escape sequences: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: You can open the file in notepad++ and see the encoding in one of the menus. If it's downloaded, chances are it's UTF-8 without BOM. VS does not understand this by default. You need to either save it as UTF-8 with BOM, or as UTF16, or probably set UTF-8 as the source charset in compiler options (I'm not terribly familiar with those).

Comment: @n.m. yes ! this worked

Comment: The BOM may be called "signature", indicated in Visual Studio as `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001`

Comment: There are VS add-ons which automatically detect UTF-8 encoding even without the signature (or whatever its name). Very handy, as UTF-8 is now the de-facto standard,